# How do I call an Azure Function through HTTP that I added to my project through Visual Studio's "Connected Services" feature?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

I'm trying to take advantage of the Connected Services feature in VS web application.
I'm trying to connect Azure Function.
I can see that after competing the add service, servicesDependencies.json is updated with reference to "compute.function.windows1".

I can see that after competing the add service, servicesDependencies.json is updated with reference to "compute.function.windows1".
Question though:
How do I consume this connected service?
I was going through the documentation but there is no clear guidance on that.
I know that I could just fire httpget, but wanted to benefit from that connected service approach.

Using VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

- I have added `Connected services` from visual studio using below steps
- Open Visual studio and create a web application and add azure function. Go to Connection strings and follow the procedure mentioned below. Before modifying any operation in the project, we need to create a app service that is enabled with HTTP and other required protocols.
- Click on the Networking section and then change the networking protocols as required.

[image]

- Then go to Visual studio and start creating function app and follow the navigation mentioned below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Choose the `Azure function`  or `Azure app service` according to your requirement.

[image]

- Choose the App service which was created under your subscription and resource group.
- The app will have all the networking protocols which are ready to consume.

[image]

- This is the app service that was created and successfully connected with the project. Now the resources are ready to consume.

Comment: Thanks, but the question was how to consume it from the code (Azure Function Connected Service). I have the function created and working and need to consume it from the web app.

Comment: What do you mean by consume the function? Do you want to make HTTP calls from your web app to your function?

Comment: Yes, I want to use that connected service to make HTTP call. I know I can make it via HTTP client and put URL but wanted to take the advantage of the connected service so configuration can change based on the environment.